# finding spectral radius of the jacobi iteration matrix

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

I am using Matlab to find the spectral radius of the Jacobi iteration matrix where `A=[4 2 1;1 3 1;1 1 4]`.

I can't seem to input the correct commands to get the size of the error after 5 iterations. Can someone help me?

Here are a list of commands that I put into Matlab so far:

```
A=[4 2 1;1 3 1;1 1 4]

A =

 4     2     1
 1     3     1
 1     1     4

 D=diagonal(diagonal(A));L=(A,-1);U=(A,1);

 b=([3 -1 4])

 x0j=zeros([0 0 0]);

 x=D\(-(U+L)*x0j+b);r=b-A*x    %Jacobi iteration.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Error using  * 
 Inputs must be 2-D, o enter code here r at least one input must be scalar.
 To compute element wise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead.
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: And what is the function `diagonal`? Do you mean [`diag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html)?

Comment: It doesn't look like right matlab code at all. Because jacobi iteration algorithm is well-known, you can easy google right implementation in matlab.

Answer (score 6):

The [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of a matrix is the maximum of the modulus of its eigenvalues. It can be simply computed using `max(abs(eig(·)))`.

However, as others have noticed, your whole code seems pretty mixed up and not actually valid Matlab code, so your problem is not really to compute the spectral radius, is it? The [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method) is very straightforward and easy to implement:

```
% diagonal part of A and rest
D = diag(diag(A));
R = A - D;

% iteration matrix and offset
T = - inv(D) * R;
C = inv(D) * b;

% spectral radius condition
rho = max(abs(eig(T)));
if rho >= 1
    error('no convergence')
end

% initial guess
x = randn(size(b));

% iteration
while norm(A * x - b) > 1e-15
    x = T * x + C;
end
```

Note that I used `inv(D)` to directly follow the description in Wikipedia, but the inverse of a diagonal matrix can be easily computed using `diag(1 ./ diag(D))`.

I don't really see why one would need to separate `R` into an upper and lower part. I suppose it has to do with numerical efficiency, but then, Matlab is a very efficient high-level language for matrix computations already. So actually there is no need to implement the Jacobi algorithm in it explicitly when you can simply write `A \ b` – except for educational purposes I guess.

Comment: `A\b` is great for deployment or general-purpose use, but it's great to implement algorithms manually for educational purposes once in a while. It can also be nice to solve a system of equations in a particular way, if you know that `A\b` gives bad results for a particular problem.